# Erros ao ler arquivos

Tags: java

Fiz um método para ler o arquivo txt que foi criado em outro método. Depois de muito tempo recebendo o NumberFormatException, consegui eliminá-lo porém o método ainda não envia nome e tempo para a minha classe JogadorRanking. Depois de uns testes tô vendo que o lerRanking não está armazenando corretamente os conteúdos das duas variáveis, só não sei o porquê.

Esse método escreve o txt:

```
try {
        if (!arquivo.exists()) {
            arquivo.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);
        BufferedWriter escrever = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        escrever.write(nome);
        escrever.newLine();
        escrever.write(tempo);
        escrever.newLine();
        escrever.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

E esse método leria o arquivo e retornaria o nome e o tempo:

```
public static JogadorRanking lerRanking(String arquivo) throws IOException {
    fileR = new FileReader(arquivo);
    buffR = new BufferedReader(fileR);
    JogadorRanking ranking = new JogadorRanking("", 0);
    String linha = buffR.readLine();
    while (linha != null) {
        String nome = linha;
        linha = buffR.readLine();
        int tempo = Integer.parseInt(linha);
        ranking.adicionaJogador(nome, tempo);
        linha = buffR.readLine();
    }
    Collections.sort(ranking.getDadosRanking());
    return ranking;
}
```

Aqui a classe JogadorRanking(um pouco resumida, óbvio), que uso para ordenar o ranking:

```
public JogadorRanking(String nome, int tempo) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.tempo = tempo;
}
public void adicionaJogador(String nome, int tempo) {
    dadosRanking.add(new JogadorRanking(nome, tempo));
}
public String retornaJogador() {
    String dados ="";
    for(JogadorRanking jogador: dadosRanking) {
        dados+=jogador.retornaNome()+" "+jogador.retornaTempo()+"\n";
    }
    return dados;
}
```

Apesar de não ter mas nenhum erro, quando chamo na main para printar o retornaJogador()[que retorna os nomes e tempos dos jogadores da lista], não aparece nada.
Se eu tento fazer um .lerRanking("...").getNome e getTempo, o nome sai vazio e o tempo 0. 
Alguém poderia por favor me indicar onde estou errando?

Comment: chega e entrar no `while`? qual o valor de `linha`?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Ele entra no while, colocando para printar o valor de linha após o primeiro buffR.readline(), recebo "linha igual a 3". No último readLine()[após int tempo = Integer.parseint e ranking.adicionaJogador], recebo linha igual a null